# Django REST Framework Saving Nested Serializers Without Creating Them

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer like so:

```
class DataSetColumnSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    custom_target = target_serializers.CustomTargetSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = dataset_models.DataSetColumn
```

`custom_target` uses the following serializer:

```
class CustomTargetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = target_models.CustomTarget
```

I'm passing back an object that includes the `custom_target` that i'd like to set for that `DataSetColumn`. When I validate the serializer and save it:

```
serializer = serializers.DataSetColumnSerializer(column, data=request.DATA)

if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
```

the `custom_target` serializer is creating a new `CustomTarget` instead of just setting the `custom_target` of that `DataSetColumn` to the object passed in. I tried setting the `CustomTargetSerializer` to readonly. That works in the sense that it doesn't create a new `CustomTarget` but it doesn't set the `custom_target` to the object either.

How can I use `serializer.save()` on a serialized `DataSetColumn` object to set the `custom_target` to the nested object passed in instead of creating a new one from the nested object?

Comment: try to rewrite serializer save method and inside, do the logic that you want.

Comment: @levi that makes sense but when overriding save_object() it seems like the nested object gets passed in the loop as well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rather 'dirty' way to do this:

In the *pre_save* handler, you can reset *custom_target* to have only the id. Something like this:

```
def pre_save(self, obj):
    if 'custom_target' in self.request.DATA:
        custom_target = self.request.DATA['custom_target']
        self.request.DATA['custom_target'] = custom_target['id']
```

Can't think of any better/ cleaner solution right now, but if I find one, I'll write it :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution most in the sense of REST Framework in my eyes would be to use a nested serializer and a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` separately. With it, you can receive `CustomTarget` nested objects as `custom_target` and can associate `CustomTarget` objects by their ID on creation supplying `custom_target_id` as POST parameter.

```
class DataSetColumnSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    custom_target = target_serializers.CustomTargetSerializer(read_only=True)
    custom_target_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source='custom_target')

class Meta:
    model = dataset_models.DataSetColumn
```

However, you will end up with two properties `custom_target` and `custom_target_id`, which may not be perceived as ideal. As a generic solution, a custom field might be implemented.

**Generic approach: Custom related field**

```
class NestedRelatedField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    def __init__(self, serializer_class, *args, **kwargs):
        self.serializer = serializer_class()
        super(NestedRelatedField, self).__init__(queryset=serializer_class.Meta.model.objects.all(), *args, **kwargs)

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return self.serializer.to_representation(instance)
```

Use it as:

```
class DataSetColumnSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    custom_target = NestedRelatedField(CustomTargetSerializer)
```